# What should be the reason for not getting output from the MOTION GC library?

Tags: stm32, gyroscope, stm32f4, stm32cubeide, mems

I'm working on the "STEVAL-MKI182V2" mounted on the `STEVAL-MKI109V3` development board. Initially, I downloaded the Standard c Drivers from the following link `https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STMems_Standard_C_drivers`  where I found the `.ioc` file called `_prj_MKI109V3` which is specifically developed for the MKI109V3 board.

Then after I have added the `ISM330DLC` driver files and example code called  `ism330dlc_read_data_polling.c` from the following link `https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STMems_Standard_C_drivers/tree/master/ism330dlc_STdC` after adding I was just calling `ism330dlc_read_data_polling` function in the main while loop.

We are using the below function to initialise the library

```
void Gyro_Initialize()
{

/ Gyroscope calibration API initialization function /
MotionGC_Initialize(MGC_MCU_STM32,&sample_freq);

/ Optional: Get version /
MotionGC_GetLibVersion(lib_version);

/ Optional: Get knobs settings /
MotionGC_GetKnobs(&knobs);

/ Optional: Adjust knobs settings /
knobs.AccThr = 0.008f;
knobs.GyroThr = 0.15;
MotionGC_SetKnobs(&knobs);

/ Optional: Set initial gyroscope offset /
start_gyro_bias.GyroBiasX = 0;
start_gyro_bias.GyroBiasY = 0;
start_gyro_bias.GyroBiasZ = 0;
MotionGC_SetCalParams(&start_gyro_bias);

/ Optional: Set sample frequency /
MotionGC_SetFrequency(&sample_freq);

}
```

After initialising the library we are sending the stored raw data (which we have received by using example code `ism330dlc_read_data_polling.c`) as an input to the function `MotionGC_Update(&data_in, &data_out, &bias_update);`

Now the issue is, after dumping the code I'm able to get the raw data from the sensor immediately after I'm calling the function `Gyro_Process()` in which where I'm trying to get the data from the function `MotionGC_Update(&data_in, &data_out, &bias_update);` as follows

```
void Gyro_Process()
{

 /** Using gyroscope calibration algorithm **/
 MGC_input_t data_in;
 MGC_output_t data_out;
 int bias_update;
 float gyro_cal_x, gyro_cal_y, gyro_cal_z;

 data_in.Acc[0] = acceleration_mg[0];
 data_in.Acc[1] = acceleration_mg[1];
 data_in.Acc[2] = acceleration_mg[2];

 data_in.Gyro[0] = angular_rate_mdps[0];
 data_in.Gyro[1] = angular_rate_mdps[1];
 data_in.Gyro[2] = angular_rate_mdps[2];

 // MotionGC_GetCalParams(&start_gyro_bias);
 // {
 //  data_out.GyroBiasX = (int32_t)(data_out.GyroBiasZ - 
  gyro_bias_to_mdps(start_gyro_bias.GyroBiasX));
 //  data_out.GyroBiasY = (int32_t)(data_out.GyroBiasY - 
  gyro_bias_to_mdps(start_gyro_bias.GyroBiasY));
 //  data_out.GyroBiasZ = (int32_t)(data_out.GyroBiasZ - 
  gyro_bias_to_mdps(start_gyro_bias.GyroBiasZ));
  // }

 / Get acceleration X/Y/Z in g /
 // MEMS_Read_AccValue(data_in.Acc[0], data_in.Acc[1], 
  data_in.Acc[2]);

 / Get angular rate X/Y/Z in dps /
  // MEMS_Read_GyroValue(data_in.Gyro[0], data_in.Gyro[1], 
  data_in.Gyro[2]);

 / Gyroscope calibration algorithm update /
  MotionGC_Update(&data_in, &data_out, &bias_update);

 / Apply correction /
 gyro_cal_x = (data_in.Gyro[0]-data_out.GyroBiasX);
 gyro_cal_y = (data_in.Gyro[1]-data_out.GyroBiasY);
 gyro_cal_z = (data_in.Gyro[2]-data_out.GyroBiasZ);

 sprintf((char *)tx_buffer,
 "Gyroscope [mg]      :%4.2f\t%4.2f\t%4.2f\r\n",gyro_cal_x, 
 gyro_cal_y, gyro_cal_z);
 CDC_Transmit_FS( tx_buffer, strlen( (char const *)tx_buffer ) 
 );

 // HAL_Delay(500);
  }
```

but here one thing I observed is that the `data_out` buffer is always zero which means the calibration buffer is not getting updated with the calibrated data.

Now, this issue I tried to post it on the ST Forum but I haven't got any help from your side felt really disappointed about the response from the ST Forum. Now I really need help because the project is getting delayed and still, we are stuck with this issue for almost 1 and a half months now.

Comment: Where is this MotionGC_Update function? Could you share some more code?

Comment: @MathiasE I'm not able to share the code in this comment but I can tell you that first I'm reading the raw data using `polling example` then I'm using example code which I got in the following file `um2181-getting-started-with-motiongc-gyroscope-calibration` on page no 6.

Comment: @Omar Hard to know what the problem could be without looking more at the code. I would really read through the documentation very carefully to see if something was missed (MotionGC_init function called?). On a sidenote the MEMS function is probably wrong, should probably be something like this -> MEMS_Read_AccValue(&data_in.Acc[0], &data_in.Acc[1], 
 &data_in.Acc[2]);

Comment: @MathiasE I will edit the question where this time I will add the init function as well. Basically we are not using `MEMS_Read_AccValue(&data_in.Acc[0], &data_in.Acc[1], &data_in.Acc[2]);` because for the same purpose we are using `ism330dlc_read_data_polling.c` file.

Comment: @Omar, what does the bias_update show ? This guy also have similar problems -> https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00001X4GpWSAV/problem-with-motiongc-library

"Please make sure you convert the input data from mg to g resp. from mdps to dps before you pass them to the library. You can use the GC_Data_Handler function in GyroscopeCalibration application which is part of the X-CUBE-MEMS1 package as a reference code and example of correct data feeding to the library."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the way I was sending the input raw data to the Motion GC library was an issue. When I checked the document I observed that the data type that which library function is expecting was different. Also, I tried a few orientation settings in the Library settings then finally it is working now.